# Cómo usar Función Shell para Excel VBA en MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Espero que estén muy bien.

Por favor, alguien podría ayudarme con esta duda. Este código que envía mensajes de información que esta en excel, a través de WhastApp, me funciona correctamente en windows, pero necesito adaptarlo para que funciones en un Excel de un ordenador MAC.

Creo entender que el problema lo tengo en la ejecución de la función SHELL que inicializa la aplicación, pero no se que adaptación debo hacer para que sea operativo en MAC.

De antemano agradezco su valiosa ayuda.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_NORMAL = 1  'para optimizar la aplicación
Sub envioCartera()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Inabilitar la pantalla
'Application.EnableEvents = False
'ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim Rango As Range
Dim x
Dim Mensaje, saludo, cuerpo, cierre, archivo As String
Dim i, fila, id1, id2, id3, y, k, t1, t2 As Integer
archivo = ThisWorkbook.Name

Call SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}", True)
'loExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'ReturnValue = Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE")
Workbooks(archivo).Activate
fila = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If fila >= 3 Then

    Hoja3.Range("c11") = Now
    
    saludo = Hoja3.Range("b4").Text
    cuerpo = " " & Hoja3.Range("c4").Text
    cierre = Hoja3.Range("d4").Text
    id1 = Hoja3.Range("B6").Value
    id2 = Hoja3.Range("C6").Value
    
    
    For i = 3 To fila
     'For Each Rango In Hoja1.Range("Cartera[Cliente]") 'Nombre de la tabla y columna
        Mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & Hoja1.Cells(i, 5).Text & Hoja1.Cells(i, 4).Value & "&text=" & saludo & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "%20" & Hoja1.Cells(i, id1) & Chr(13) & "%20" & cuerpo & " " & FormatCurrency(Hoja1.Cells(i, id2), 0) & " " & cierre, " ", "%20")
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        x = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", Mensaje, &O0, &O0, SW_NORMAL)  'Para obtener el mensaje
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:06")
        
            Call SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}", True)
            Call SendKeys("~", True)  'El caracter ~ es para presionar enter y enviar el mensaje
            Call SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}", True)
            
        
        Next i


'AppActivate "Excel", 1
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate   'Volver la ventana
Hoja1.Select
Call SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}", True)
Hoja3.Range("c12") = Now
MsgBox ("Mensaje con Exito"), vbInformation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Habilitar la pantalla lo que hace
Application.EnableEvents = True

Else
MsgBox "No hay contactos", vbCritical, "excelparatodos.com"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No testeado, pero el equivalente de Shell en Mac, al ser sistemas operativos diferentes, es el objeto Función MacScript

> [Función
> MacScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/macscript-function)

Mira también esta respuesta en SO:

[How to run shell command on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248873/how-to-run-shell-command-on-mac)

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda @Esei